# regarding http compression with gzip or deflate in asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, compression

actually i don't know anything about http compression. i search google and got many code to implement http compression for asp.net web site. i just need to know what is the advantage of using http compression. does it reduce the page size or does it help page to download on client pc much faster.

i use one http module which implement http compression the code as follows.

[enter link description here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Jun/29/HttpWebRequest-and-GZip-Http-Responses)

[enter link description here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/02/ASPNET-GZip-Encoding-Caveats)

just go to the link and tell me if i use those technique then my page size will be reduce and load faster. looking for advise.
thanks

Comment: why negative mark...i juts ask for concept.

Comment: "what is the advantage of using http compression" - "approximately 2 630 000 results". To quote the first hit, "a capability built into both browsers and servers that can dramatically improve site performance by reducing the amount of time required to transfer data between the server and the client". So, yes, it reduces the size; less size == smaller transfer time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Piskvor is right it is a simple answer to get by searching it.

If you are using IIS 7.5 (maybe 7.0 as well I am not 100% sure) then it is simple to turn on HTTP Compression through the server. If you turn on static and dynamic compression then you will see your responses will then be compressed.

Benefits include much smaller transmission size - so it will be sent much faster.

There is a tradeoff for the smaller page size but a higher CPU overhead (as the webserver will have to do more work to send the file) but for modern web servers this is more than reasonable.

If you are not using IIs7+ then you will have to implement the solutions as specified.

Does that help at all?

Comment: if IIS can compress then why people write own code for page compression...any reason.

Comment: Sometimes you don't have that level of control on your webserver. From your first link 'It's pretty straight forward to use GZip compression either by letting IIS do it for you automatically or by using some simple ASP.NET code to compress content.'